# C# where does Console.WriteLine came from

Tags: c#, namespaces, console-application

i'm a c# learner. And i don't understand the way my instructor taught us. So what i did is install Visual Studio 2017 at home and try to do what we did in school.

I don't understand, reference. the one in the solution explorer. the one called intelisense, and the code above `using System;`

Upon on my research. The reference tab in the solution explorer are libraries or collection of precompiled codes to be used in our program.

So what i did Removed all the library reference to the program. But why does `Console.WriteLine` still works? Is there a library reference to this? or what dll does System namespace use?

And can someone please explain what does code are used for? our instructor teach us by just reading what he searched in the internet. No explanation at all he's expecting us newbies to know technical stuff like this from the start.

```
`using System;` 

namespace Hello_World
class Program
intelisense
```

What i only understand is the reference in the solution explorer does and the main method is the start up of the program. Which all code inside it will be executed first when we run our program.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: System is referenced in the 'Assemblies' tab. Right click on our project -> Add -> Reference.. -> Assemblies -> Framework

Comment: This is too big a topic to be answered in a paragraph or so. You need to buy a book or follow a tutorial; I recommend [CLR via C#](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/clr-via-c-sharp-9780735667457).

Comment: You can start to learn the hard way. Forget VS. Open your notepad, write a program, save it as something.cs and use the command line compiler csc. Now you have to deal with all those references, but be sure you'll learn a lot of things.

Comment: There is one assembly that is *always* referenced and does not appear in your project's references list.  It is mscorlib, the "core library" of .NET.  It contains essential types that every program needs, like System.String.  And the Console class.

Comment: Thank you for those explanation, its better than how my instructor explains

Answer (score 4):

Your question is really, really broad.. You might want to consider asking more specific questions.

That said, I'll try to answer some of your questions.

First off, a library, in your case *.dll files, contains code, i.e. classes, methods, etc.
You can reference this code in your project by including those libraries into your project. You can then access e.g. the methods in the library from your own code.

By `using System;` you are including a so called **namespace**. Imagine that, as some sort of, let's say, container, where some related objects reside.

The System namespace is defined in the mscorlib.dll library, and inside that `System` namespace, there is a class, called `Console`.
This mscorlib.dll library is **automatically** included/referenced in your Visual Studio project. `Console.WriteLine` does still work, because the reference to the mscorlib.dll is still existing and you are `using System;`.
Without that using-statement, it would still work, but only if you typed `System.Console.WriteLine();`, because that's what the `using` actually does: it includes the namespace into your *.cs file, so you don't have to type the namespaces/assemblies of all the classes you are using every time.

`class Program` declares a class named "Program", even though it is not complete.
For explanations on classes, you could start with the [Microsoft C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

As for your problem regarding Intellisense; I'm not really sure, what is unclear about that. In general, Intellisense is an autocomplete feature offered by Microsoft in Visual Studio. It also contains code snippets and some more useful stuff.

In the end, in case your teacher does not provide sufficient information on the subjects, I would really recommend that you simply start reading stuff about (C#) programming in general, starting from the scratch. There are plenty of great tutorials on the internet, explaining somewhat every aspect of programming. A good place for C#/.NET are of course the Microsoft topics on their respective pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your explanation makes a difference on my understanding about the question now, your explanation makes it easier for me to understand things. And i'm gonna read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **rqnn** and i think you need some time and a lot of tutorials to ask this kind of question and process the answer becouse it is a large topic.
Recommendations to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXmVym6L8dw&list=PLAC325451207E3105 tutorials about c# as well as .Net program execution.

Maybe this illustration about namespace will help you process **rqnn's** answer.

```
using System;
using MySystem; 

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
         public static void Main(string [] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");      
            MyConsole.MyWriteLine("Hello world");

            //other way (then you wouldn't need using System and using MySystem)

            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world01");
            MySystem.MyConsole.MyWriteLine("Hello world01");

        }

    }   
}

// I've created my own namespace
namespace MySystem
{
    class MyConsole
    {
       public static void MyWriteLine(string message)
        {
          //  some complex code that displays message on console(in short term)
        }
    }

}
```

In **Main** method i am calling my own namespace that i created, and my own method that i created as well as **WriteLine** method.Hope u can find similarity when calling these methods.

Comment: Thank you for the example. stackoverflow is really a good website. Thank you for sharing your knowledge